# In PostgreSQL, add a column with unique values according to specific column ordering / sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

**Background**

I've got a PostgreSQL table, `db1`, that's got several columns in it but no primary key. I need to add one. Postgres is version 13-point-something, running on a local server on a 64bit Windows PC. Here's a toy version of the table:

```
+-------------------+------------+
|member             |service_date|
+-------------------+------------+
|eof81j4            |2011-01-06  |
|eof81j4            |2010-06-03  |
|eof81j4            |2010-01-12  |
|eof81j4            |2011-05-21  |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |
|p8ur0fq            |2014-01-13  |
|p8ur0fq            |2016-04-04  |
|p8ur0fq            |2014-01-13  |
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |
|akj3vie            |2009-03-31  |
+-------------------+------------+
```

Note here that the table isn't ordered in any obvious way: the `member` column isn't in ABC order, say, and the `service_date` column isn't ordered chronologically or anything.

**The Problem**

Typically, I'd add a primary key to a table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE db1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

And that works just fine. However, because of some queries I have to run later on, I'd like the primary key to be applied as if the table were ordered (sorted, in other words) first by `member` (ascending alphabetical order) and, within that, chronologically (from oldest to newest) by `service date`. In other words I'd like something like this:

```
+-------------------+------------+--+
|member             |service_date|id|
+-------------------+------------+--+
|akj3vie            |2009-03-31  |1 |
|eof81j4            |2010-01-12  |2 |
|eof81j4            |2010-06-03  |3 |
|eof81j4            |2011-01-06  |4 |
|eof81j4            |2011-05-21  |5 |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |6 |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |7 |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |8 |
|p8ur0fq            |2014-01-13  |9 |
|p8ur0fq            |2014-01-13  |10|
|p8ur0fq            |2016-04-04  |11|
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |12|
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |13|
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |14|
+-------------------+------------+--+
```

**What I've Tried**

Attempts at cracking this have gone something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE db1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ORDER BY member, service_date
```

But that yields `[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"`. I've looked for similar posts on SO, but solutions seem to involve creating a new table, and I'd prefer not to do that (as the real table I'm going to be doing this on is very very large).

**EDIT**

Upon reflection, and thanks in part to Gordon Linoff's answer below, I'm realizing that I don't actually need this new column to be a Primary Key in the formal sense that Postgres recognizes it as such. All I *really* need is a column with unique values for each row that are ordered in the way I described. Whether it's formally a PK or not doesn't actually matter. (In the original title and body of this post, I had asked for a Primary Key. I've edited things to reflect that that's not strictly necessary.)

Comment: There is no `ORDER BY` on a `PRIMARY KEY`. SQL data is unordered unless you use an `ORDER BY` in the selection query.

Comment: So is what I'm asking for help with not possible, in your view?

Comment: It is not possible. The closest you can come is [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-cluster.html) but that is basically a temporary thing for any table in which data is being updated. You can also set an `INDEX`, but first I would establish that it really necessary as an index has overhead. Right now I think you are in the realm of premature optimization.

Comment: Can I order the table first somehow, and then apply the PK as I normally would?

Comment: Never design a table where you need a surrogate key to have any property other than uniqueness.  A huge list of events can cause gaps, out of order allocation, etc.  Where order is relevent, use the `service_date` ***in your queries***, such as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY member, service_date)`.  *(To be more clear about your specific question; the answer is `don't try, you can't reliably achieve this, and should never need to`.)*

Comment: I repeat: 'SQL data is unordered'. And as of now you have not established there is a problem.

Comment: Representing/managing a(n ordered) list in a relational/SQL DB is a faq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add the `id` column, set the value and then convert it to an identity.  You have to be careful, because you want the numbering to start at 15 (for your sample data):

```
alter table db1 add column id int not null default 0;
update db1
    set id = d.new_id
    from (select db1.*, db1.ctid, row_number() over (order by member, service_date) as new_id
          from db1
         ) d
    where db1.ctid = d.ctid;

alter table db1 alter column id drop default;

alter table db1 alter column id add generated always as identity  (start with 15) ;

alter table db1 add primary key (id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5493786bbe661eb48a555f708dabd34) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Just know an `IDENITY` is backed by `sequence` and a `sequence` is not guaranteed to be gap less or necessarily sequential.  Per @MatBailie you are counting on something to happen that may very well not.

Comment: @Gordon, this works just fine on my end. I'm not sure that I'm going to use it on my real dataset, if for no other reason that I won't be able to audit whether it works properly on all ~200m rows, but I'd say this is a great proof of concept. Reflecting now, I don't actually need the column to formally be PK -- I just needed a unique sequence of some kind according to the parameters I mentioned. I'll update my post to reflect this.

Comment: @logjammin . . . You can use the same code, just remove the primary key constraint.  However a serial/identity column would normally be the primary key anyway.